# Strange notation in Vue: const { state = {} } = this.$store;

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, notation

I'm following a project already created, and I ran across this notation in a Vue project with Vuex:

```
const { state = {} } = this.$store;
const { orders = {} } = state;
```

It seems to be defining a local object named state that is set equal to the value of the Vuex store... and then setting that equal to another object called "orders" but I'm a little lost on the notation itself. namely what this indicates:

```
{ variable = {} } = anotherObj
```

and also what this notation is called if it exists. (so that I can google it and figure out how it handles deep cloning, etc since it seems to be a way to clone objects.)... or maybe it's something particular to vuex?

Comment: [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
const { state = {} } = this.$store;
```

is [*destructuring assignment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with a *default value* if the source (`this.$store`) either doesn't have the property `state` or has it but with the value `undefined`. The result will be that `state` will have the value of `this.$store.state` if that property exists and doesn't have the value `undefined`, or will have a new blank object if the property doesn't exist or has the value `undefined`.

Example (using a string instead of an object, but it's the same principal):

```js
const obj1 = {};
const { a = "default" } = obj1;
console.log(a);        // "default"

const obj2 = {
    b: "value from obj2"
};
const { b = "default" } = obj2;
console.log(b);        // "value from obj2"
```

Comment: holy smokes is that a useful notation! Thank you so much!

Comment: @WilliamTerrill - Yeah, it's pretty cool. Like anything, you can go too far with it, but it's pretty darned cool. :-)

Comment: @WilliamTerrill - Just FWIW, I have a book coming out on this stuff in 3-4 months: [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Toys-T-J-Crowder/dp/1119367956/)

Comment: Wow... thanks!  I checked out your blog as well.  There's some nice info there!